# Changing non-combination keys like 'S' and ' G'

Tags: shortcut, customization, keymap

**Found the solution while writing the question, but decided still to post for others that might be as stupid as I am. Solution at bottom of post.**

I'm planning on moving to a different keyboard layout like Dvorak, Colemak or Workman on a split keyboard. Many normal keys like 'S' for Scale and 'G' for Grab are likely to be placed on the right hand side, but my right hand is using the mouse.

Is there any way to assign new keys to those functions? The keymap tab in preferences doesn't seem to show anything for grab or scale.

And solutions to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23360/dvorak-keyboard-mapping) question seem very janky. If I put in some text object I don't want to be typing in Qwerty suddenly for example. I just want to remap the simple functions.

Edit:
Apparently it's S for 'Sresize' and G for 'Gmove'... and these functions are actually just right there in the keymap tab in preferences. The solution to the problem was that there actually is no problem except a lack of braincells on my part.

Comment: S for Scale and G for Grab actually, hence the letters used!

Comment: @JohnEason except the commands are S for Resize and G for Move.  If you look for scale or grab in the keymap you won't find those commands associated with those keys.  scale and grab are just useful mnemonics.

Comment: @MartyFouts True, but that's how folks usually remember them.